# How do I respond to a buffer/stack overflow

Tags: security

How do I respond to a stack/buffer overflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Answer (score 4):

1. Disable.

   Take the service offline. This will help prevent further damage.
2. Verify.

   Make sure that the issue is reproducible.
3. Find.

   Inspect the code to see what the cause is.
4. Repair.

   Effect the changes required to ensure that the issue does not happen again due to the same cause.